# evaluate if integral converge & determine antiderivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

The problem is i need to 
study the convergence of **A** and **B**
and find the  antiderivative  of **C**
 $$A=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x) +x}{\sqrt x + x^3}dx$$ $$B=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt {e^x-1}(x^2+x^{1/3}  )}dx$$
$$C=\int\frac{1}{x}\sqrt\frac{2-x}{2+x}dx$$

in **C** i try substitution  **$$U =\sqrt\frac{2-x}{2+x}$$**

Comment: Any tries on A or B? For C, the substitution looks good. Didn't it work out for you?

Comment: by the way that was in my exam yesterday ,how u find it ?

Comment: i try but i fail look

Comment: in C  the problem is 1 over x that make the problem

Comment: You should let $u=\sqrt{(2-x)/(2+x)}$. Then you can solve for $x$. You write $U=\sqrt{(2-x)/(2+x)}\,dx$ (with the extra $dx$). That does not really make sense.

Comment: ohhh  dx   I did not mean it incident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi sami i look if the problem C  u need to use substitution 5 time 
$$u=\dfrac{1}{x+2}$$
& then after that 
$$X=\sqrt{4u-1}$$
&
$$w=X+1$$
&

....

but the final answer is $$\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{-\dfrac{x-2}{x+2}}-1\right|\right)-\ln\left(\sqrt{-\dfrac{x-2}{x+2}}+1\right)+2\arctan\left(\sqrt{-\dfrac{x-2}{x+2}}\right)+C$$

Comment: the A & B u cant do them directe because u cant find the antiderivative